# Node.js/Firebase Service Account Removed but Still Validates?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase to authenticate users on my site. I use the firebase client sdk to get idtokens in the frontend and then I send them to the backend on every api call to be verifed with the firebase admin sdk. I have a service account set up in my firebase console but recently due to a security concern, I removed the firebase service account and created a new one. I deleted all of the service accounts first from my firebase project and then attempted to refresh a page or access anything that would call my api. For some reason, my tokens were still verified, allegedly using my now deleted firebase service account (that should not exist anymore). I tried this a number of times but I don't understand. The service account is not there, therefore, the verification of the idtoken should fail in some way. What am I missing?

**frontend**

```js
export async function firebaseLoginGooglePopup(route) {
    let provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    let auth = getAuth();
    return signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then( async (userCredential) => {
        let token = userCredential._tokenResponse.idToken;
        // store in session, send to backend on each api call
    }).catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        if(errorCode == 'auth/operation-not-allowed')
            console.log('Auth not linked for user');
        else 
            console.log('Failed to login!');
    });
}
```

**backend**

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); // for service account
const { getAuth } = require("firebase-admin/auth"); // for token decoding
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Loaded from environment variables
const serviceAccount = {
    type: firebasetype,
    project_id: firebaseprojectID,
    private_key_id: firebaseprivatekeyID,
    private_key: firebaseprivatekey?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    client_email: firebaseclientemail,
    client_id: firebaseclientID,
    auth_uri: firebaseauthuri,
    token_uri: firebasetokenuri,
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: firebaseauthprovidercert,
    client_x509_cert_url: firebaseclientcerturl
  };
  
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  });

  console.log('Firebase should be connected');


// Grab token from header and verify it using admin sdk
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization'] ? req.headers['authorization'].split(" ") : null;
    if(!token){
        console.log('No header provided');
        res.status(403).json('Forbidden');
    }
    else if(!token[1]){
        console.log('No token detected');
        res.status(403).json('Forbidden');
    }
    else
    {
        let auth = getAuth();
        auth.verifyIdToken(token[1])
        .then((decodedToken) => {
            console.log("Server: auth token verified");
            next();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Auth expired!'});
        });
    }
}
```

Express uses isAuthenticated on every api call before proceeding to get anything else. The token is there accordingly and looks accurate based on checks with the client sdk. If it fails at the verification in the backend it should send a 401. I know the token and the environment variables for a new service account are accurate (console logged and checked so I know I'm using a new service account). I don't get it though. If the service account doesn't exist, how could this possibly still verify the token?

Also, while on the IAM page after I deleted my service account I noticed a principal "firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com" showed up. I assume this is a default that gets created automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your backend server: Simply restarting your backend server should clear any cached credentials and force the Firebase Admin SDK to reinitialize with the new service account.

Explicitly clear the credential cache: You can explicitly clear the credential cache by calling `admin.app().delete()` before initializing Firebase Admin again. Here's how you can modify your backend code to achieve this:

```
// Before re-initializing Firebase Admin, delete the existing app
if (admin.apps.length > 0) {
    admin.app().delete()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Firebase app deleted");
            // Proceed to re-initialize Firebase Admin with the new service account
            admin.initializeApp({
                credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error deleting Firebase app:", error);
        });
} else {
    // Proceed to initialize Firebase Admin with the new service account
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
    });
}
```

Regarding the principal "firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com", this might indeed be a default service account created automatically. However, it's usually not directly related to your project's service account used for authentication purposes. It might be used internally by Firebase for certain management tasks. Deleting your project's service account should not affect this default service account.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have restarted the backend several times in the process of testing this (assuming there was a cache) and somehow, it seemed to still validate tokens using the old service account that doesn't exist. Is there a setting in GCP that needs to be changed?

Comment: There isn't a specific setting in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) that directly influences Firebase authentication token verification. However, ensure that your GCP project settings, such as IAM roles and permissions, are correctly configured to align with your authentication requirements. Additionally, review any GCP services or configurations related to identity and access management for potential impacts on Firebase authentication.